# Making a "2048 solitaire game" with F#: creating the functions for the implementation file (.fs file)

Tags: f#, 2048

I am tasked with creating a version of the 2048 game. This version is on a 3x3 field, and uses colors (instead of numbers). The functions that I will need have already been given to me. Among these, I have to make a filter function, which I am having trouble figuring out how to implement. The filter function is defined as shown below with some examples which make perfect sense to me.

```
type pos = int*int // A 2 - dimensional vector in board - coordinats (not pixels)
type value = Red | Green | Blue | Yellow | Black // piece values
type piece = value*pos //
type state = piece list // the board is a set of randomly organized pieces

val filter: k: int -> s: state -> state

// return the list of pieces on a column k on board s, e.g. ,
// > filter 0 [( Blue , (1 , 0)); (Red , (0 , 0))];;
// val it: state = [( Blue , (1 , 0)); (Red , (0 , 0))]
// > filter 1 [( Blue , (1 , 0)); (Red , (0 , 0))];;
// val it: state = []
```

My thoughts are:

- To use some kind of pattern matching, specific to this case of a 3x3 board, with k columns being {0, 1, 2}

```
let filter (k: int) (s: state) : state =
 match k with
  | 0 -> 
  | 1 -> 
  | 2 ->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `state` is a `List<piece>` I would use `List.filter`. Within the filter predicate you can "deconstruct" the state and verify whether `k` equals `column`:

```
let filter (k: int) (s: state) : state = 
  s |> List.filter(fun (pieceValue, (row, column)) -> k = column)
```

Note that we can also ignore unused values by using `_`.

```
let filter (k: int) (s: state) : state = 
  s |> List.filter(fun (_, (_, column)) -> k = column)
```

We can also remove all the explicit types in these functions as they are inferred automatically by the F# compiler.

```
let filter k s = 
  s |> List.filter(fun (_, (_, column)) -> k = column)
```

And to make it even shorter we can even remove the explicit pipe of `s` into `List.filter`:

```
let filter k = List.filter (fun (_, (_, column)) -> k = column)
```

Now you can see that the filter for you game state is nothing more than a `List.filter` with a specific predicate.

Also, I know the functions you have to implement are given, but still consider renaming this function to something like `column` and `k` to `c` or `col` :).

```
/// The `piece`s in the given column `col`.
let column col = List.filter (fun (_, (_, column)) -> col = column)
```

Comment: Awesome Okke :)
In terms of the renaming, I presume it's to avoid a mixup with F#'s List.filter and "filter"?

Comment: I think that `column` better describes what the binding does. It returns only the specified column of the state. Naming it like this will give you very understandable usage in my opinion, for example: `state |> column 3 |> doStuffWithColumn`.